# iPhone downloadable widget, software how to?

Tags: android, iphone, widget

I would like to create a little application for iPhone or Android smart phones. It's a little Javascript application on my webpage. A price calculator. How can I make it for downloadable and installable on smart phones?

This is [my application](http://mikrobusz-berles.com/kalkulator.html). I would like to use as a smart phone application, I know it's a very simple app, but it's good for a start. Can you help me with a tutorial, or something? (sorry about my poor English...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it around a native app in [Phonegap/Cordova](http://phonegap.com/).

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, the user can "download" your app by tapping the "share" button and choosing "add to home screen".

You can add a few `link` tags to specify a suitable icon for your app, hide the address bar, and maybe the status bar. See [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/ipad/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/configuringwebapplications/configuringwebapplications.html)